# Angular strap datepicker dynamic startDate/endDate

Tags: dynamic, angularjs, datepicker, angular-strap

I have a scenario where I have a "parent" datepicker and a bunch of "child" datepickers, all within the same view. I will need to update the child pickers to be limited by the parent's date and the parent picker will need to be governed by the highest child date. I've tried setting this on the children pickers:

```
//child pseudo-code
<input data-date-end-date="parent.target_date" data-ng-model="child.target_date bs-datepicker />

//parent pseudo-code
<input data-date-start-date="highestChild.target_date" data-ng-model="child.target_date bs-datepicker />
```

but i just get a picker without the ability to select anything.

essentially a child should not be able to be put out passed it's parent and a parent can't be pulled in closer than it's highest child, but they all need to be able to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem with your code is that Angular-Strap does not use `data-date-*` attributes, it uses `data-*`, which is unfortunately not well documented at the moment (if at all).

Another problem is that the `start-date` and `end-date` attributes normally work (when using only Bootstrap datepicker without Angular-Strap) by entering in a static date such as `data-date-start-date="2013-09-03"`.  Angular-Strap works the same way as many other Angular directives by letting you use the attribute like you normally would without Angular, but allowing you to use an Angular expression by using double curly brackets.

Eg `ng-href="http://www.waddup.com/items/{{ item.number }}"`

Your pseudo-code should end up being something like this:

```
//child pseudo-code
<input
    data-end-date="{{ parent.target_date}}"
    data-ng-model="child.target_date"
    bs-datepicker
/>

//parent pseudo-code
<input
    data-start-date="{{ highestChild.target_date }}"
    data-ng-model="parent.target_date"
    bs-datepicker
/>
```

Comment: This makes sense. I did try this and was able to get the start and end dates working. The datepicker seems to be finicky about the format of the date it gets. `MM/dd/yyy` works but `yyyy-MM-dd` doesn't. This seems a bit strange. I can't figure out if it has to do with the config setting for format or the way the date is getting passed.

Comment: Try `data-format="yyyy-mm-dd"`

You probably also have to do `data-type="string"` since datepicker likes to use the JavaScript Date object rather than strings.

Comment: That did the trick. I think the date-type="string" was the key thing there. So it seems like the format is how the picker accepts input AND how it will display. Would be nice to have an option for both. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Still having some issues. Setting the date on the picker, I'm using a date object. This works fine being set on data-ng-model. Using a date object as the start/endDate doesn't do anything if added in the data-attr. If I parse the endDate as a string, it only works if it is in the same format that the picker is set too.

Comment: Hmm, this is an issue with Angular-Strap datepicker directive.  You should make a new issue on the Github repo about this.  I can probably fix it since I mostly understand Angular directives and have familiarity with this particular one, but I'm not sure when I'd have time to.

Comment: I found a solution in another post. Ended up creating $watch on the endDate and parsing the date to the appropriate string format that way and then just setting another scope variable to handle it. `$scope.$watch('parentGoal.target_date', function(v){
      var d          = new Date(v);
      var curr_date  = d.getDate();
      var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
      var curr_year  = d.getFullYear();

      $scope.modDate = curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year;
      console.log($scope.modDate)
    })` Then set `data-end-date="{{modDate}}"`Thanks.

Comment: Bleh, that stuff ought to go in a directive, but hey, if it works, it works.  It's still a problem with Angular-Strap though.  I'll create an issue for it eventually if you don't.  Glad I could help!